# Combine annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations

How can I combine annotations in Java?

**EDIT** I was asking if I two annotations a and b, can I combine to a single annotations c?
If possible, how do I do that?

Comment: You're going to need to add more details.  What exactly do you mean by combine them?  Do you mean how do you add an annotation to an annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have multiple annotations on a single element, you can just list them in sequence.

The [Wikipedia page on Java annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) has quite a few useful examples, e.g.

```
  @Entity                      // Declares this an entity bean
  @Table(name = "people")      // Maps the bean to SQL table "people"
  class Person implements Serializable {
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot combine the annotations by e.g. annotating the annotations, unless the annotation consumer will process the meta-annotation tree explicitly. For example, Spring supports such feature for [`@Transactional`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701376/rollback-on-every-checked-exception-whenever-i-say-transactional/3702099#3702099), `@Component` and some other annotations (you may wish to have a look at [`SpringTransactionAnnotationParser#parseTransactionAnnotation()`](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~raw,r=1134/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.java)). Nice to have this feature in Java core, but alas...

However you can declare the common parent class that has a set of annotations you need and extend it. But this is not always applicable.

Comment: True, I tried annotating @ SimulationEntity with @ Entity, but it didn't work, JPA won't recognize @ Entity as meta-annotation.