# Rollback on every checked exception, whenever I say @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpa-2.0

Since the programmer is forced to catch all checked exception, I to throw checked exception in case of any problem. I would like to rollback on any of those expections. Writing `rollbackFor=Exception.class`on every `@Transactional` annotation is very error-prone, so I would like to tell spring, that: "whenever I write `@Transactional`, I mean `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)`".

I know, that I could create a custom annotation, but that seems unnatural.

So is there a way to tell spring how it should handle checked excpetions *globally*?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Custom Shortcut Annotations

> I know, that I could create a custom
>   annotation, but that seems unnatural.

No, this is exactly the use case for a Custom Annotation. Here's a quote from [Custom Shortcut Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes) in the Spring Reference:

> If you find you are repeatedly using
>   the same attributes with
>   @Transactional  on many different
>   methods, then Spring's meta-annotation
>   support allows you to define custom
>   shortcut annotations for your specific
>   use cases.

### Sample Code

And here's a sample annotation for your use case:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

Now annotate your services and / or methods with `@MyAnnotation` (you'll think of a better name). This is well-tested functionality that works by default. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Ok, but isn't it confusing, that you have an annotation, which does something like `@Transactional`, but have some other naming?

Comment: If you really want to you can of course call your annotation `@Transactional` as well, but I guess that's very error-prone because you always have to check that you use the right import. But I agree, there's not really a better name for this than `@Transactional`. But how about `@WithTransaction` for example?

Comment: Despite of my PoV in the original question, this way seems to me the least wrong, so I accept this one.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me with AspectJ. The APJClosure classes are not created when I use the "extended" annotation. Any idea why? Can I overcome this somehow?

Comment: @Dikla that sounds like a very specific scenario. I'd recommend you ask a separate question. Also, a lot has changed over the last 10 years (since this question was asked and answered)

Comment: Thanks, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/q/62875839/59241

Answer (score 17):

Approach with custom annotation looks good and straightforward, but if you actually don't want to use it, you can create a custom `TransactionAttributeSource` to modify interpretation of `@Transactional`:

```
public class RollbackForAllAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource 
    extends AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource {
    @Override
    protected TransactionAttribute determineTransactionAttribute(
            AnnotatedElement ae) {
        TransactionAttribute target = super.determineTransactionAttribute(ae);
        if (target == null) return null;
        else return new DelegatingTransactionAttribute(target) {
            @Override
            public boolean rollbackOn(Throwable ex) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And instead of `<tx:annotation-driven/>` you configure it manually as follows (see source of `AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser`):

```
<bean id = "txAttributeSource"
    class = "RollbackForAllAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource" />

<bean id = "txInterceptor"
    class = "org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name = "transactionManagerBeanName" value = "transactionManager" />
    <property name = "transactionAttributeSource" ref = "txAttributeSource" />
</bean>

<bean
    class = "org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource" ref = "txAttributeSource" />
    <property name = "adviceBeanName" value = "txInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

Also you need `<aop:config/>` or `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`.

However note that such overrides may be confusing for other developers who expect a normal behaviour of `@Transactional`.

Comment: That's the nice thing about spring, it's extensible on all levels (+1)

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- catch and wrap the checked exception into an unchecked exception - `throw new RuntimeException(checkedException)`
- create a proxy around the method, using `MethodInterceptor` (or `@AroundInvoke`, or any other means to create aspects in spring), declare it to be executed before the `<tx:annotation-driven />` by specifying `order="1"` and `order="2"` and catch and wrap there.

Comment: The first one is not an option, I would definitely force the user to catch all exceptions. Creating a proxy around the method seems to add extra complexity to the program :(

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can configure a transactional advice based on method name like this:
(from [the Spring 2.0 docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back))

> Exactly which Exception types mark a transaction for rollback can be configured. Find below a snippet of XML configuration that demonstrates how one would configure rollback for a checked, application-specific Exception type.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NoProductInStockException"/>
      <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: that's a very good option, if he wants not to go for `@Transactional`. But both don't mix well, and one should be careful.

Comment: +1 Yep, Bozho, that's my problem. _You cannot mix them._ I have setter injections, which are not transactionals, and I cannot predict by method name which methods are readonly.

Comment: I would not like to add extra magic, and rely on method naming conventions.