# Catch exception on @Transaction annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, transactional

I'm using Spring and Hibernate.

I have a class annotated as @Transactional and I want to be able to catch the exception generated by the Spring annotation without using a try catch block.

The exception is due to database connection loss.

I have many calls to methods on transactional classes and the process for managing the exception is always the same, so I just want something to call a method when an exception is raised.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to either use AspectJ AfterThrowing or customize your Annotation

[Rollback on every checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701376/rollback-on-every-checked-exception-whenever-i-say-transactional)