# spring : Input page forwarding when exception like struts

Tags: spring-4

Business validations are implemented by throwing CustomeException(key) such that user will be displayed error messages when something goes wrong.

I have to forward to input jsp (like struts) when business exception raised, to correct the user actions then continue with application.

we have custom HandlerExceptionResolverImpl to handle the all exceptions at once place. when exception raised then we don't know the input page.

How to do this in spring4 like struts ?

Please suggest the way how to accomplish this?

Thanks 
Dhorrairaajj

[base requirement is explained in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078024/spring-transaction-management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, all controllers should extends CustomeWebReq Class, which has getter method to get the input page like `String getInputPage(String path)`. Controllers are responsible to return the input page based on the servlet path argument. `getInputPage(string path)` method will be invoked from HandlerExceptionMapping where exceptions are handling.

Thanks

Dhorrairaajj